# How to create custom module (CRUD) in shopify? Like, Product and Navigation

Tags: shopify, liquid, slate

I am new in Shopify and My requirement to add more than one custom module in Shopify.
Like, admin panel (back end) side manage all module (CRUD).

I also developed a custom theme in Shopify with slate and liquid.
But, I have no idea about the custom module.

Anyone can share any docs and reference sites to related this topic.

Anyone any idea?

Comment: It is not possible to add anything/functionality in the Shopify admin panel, however, you can use Shopify Admin API to make a custom public/private app ( or plugin ) that can perform CRUD operation on any Shopify Object via API. The below link might help you. https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference

Comment: Ok, thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make this with custom app(module/plugin) [shopify documentation](https://shopify.dev/concepts/apps#custom-apps)

But you should understand how Shopify module works. You can't access direct to database and crate new database tables and rows, or create backend backend code on shopify, but you can manipulate data (products, orders, discounts, etc..) through [shopify api](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference) and send data into liquid template or pages. Good example, and tutorial for PHP developers is there [(Shopify app development in PHP)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tX1E8fuesSE&list=PL-k7XHuPgeIsv2Q6QtJR__h3kkpmqNpH0)

If you want crate new data source (For example Blog, Comments or something like that) then you should crate that part on another server (Backend part) and connect with your app (module/plugin), and after that you can use data from another server in your Shopify templates or pages. Good example, and tutorial for PHP developers is there [(Shopify app development in PHP)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tX1E8fuesSE&list=PL-k7XHuPgeIsv2Q6QtJR__h3kkpmqNpH0)